# UI Testing tool android from ADT21

Tags: android, testing

Trying to get the android UI Testing that comes as part of ADT21 (http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) to work currently and I seem to be running into some issues.

After creating a test we have to set it up as a uitest-project, the web page tells us the command is:

```
<android-sdk>/tools/android uitest-project -n <name> -t 1 -p <path>
```

But this appears to be incorrect and it should be:

```
<android-sdk>/tools/android create uitest-project -n <name> -t 1 -p <path>
```

But on running this I get the error:

```
Error: UI test projects can only target API 16 and above
```

Which i assume related to the -t parameter, i have then since tried all the values from 1 to 18 (a version of android that doesn't even exist yet) and it gives me the same error. Anyone figured it out? I assume it is going to be something simple.

Comment: whats your minsdk level in your manifest.xml ?

Comment: Thats not how it works, there is no manifest file...

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The answer was really simple. Examples shows you 1, what the -t actually wants is a target but the id is dependant on the results of running the command:

```
android list targets
```

This command will give you a list of targets you can use with IDs dependant on what you have installed on your system.

For example on my system i got:

---

```
id: 37 or "android-16"
 Name: Android 4.1.2
 Type: Platform
 API level: 16
 Revision: 3
 Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
 ABIs : armeabi-v7a, mips, x86
```

So i use the command

```
android create uitest-project -n <name> -t 37 -p <path>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is instead of using numbers which are subject to change you can use a constant string.

Example:
    : android list targets

```
Available Android targets:

id: 1 or "android-11"
.....
id: 5 or "android-17"
     Name: Android 4.2.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 17
     Revision: 2
     Skins: HVGA, QVGA, WQVGA400, WQVGA432, WSVGA, WVGA800 (default), WVGA854, WXGA720, WXGA800, WXGA800-7in
     ABIs : armeabi-v7a
...


$ android create uitest-project -n project -t "android-17" -p project 
Added file project/build.xml
```